# Can the USB ports on a Lenovo Yoga 3 laptop stay powered when Ubuntu 15.04 suspends?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, usb, power, suspend

I can't find a BIOS setting to keep the USB ports powered on suspend. Wondering if Ubuntu can keep them alive? I just want them powered so some devices (phone) attached to the ports can carry on charging while Ubuntu is suspended (I don't care about battery drain - the laptop is normally plugged into power).

Comment: What color is the plastic part inside the port ? Black is USB2, blue USB3 and yellow is Suspended-powered ports usually, which are determined by BIOS settings

Comment: The port I'd like to keep powered during suspend is blue (USB 3). Any way?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it seems it does stay powered after all, but the particular device I had plugged in just had to be unplugged and replugged (while suspended) in order for it to continue charging. More of an issue with the device I had plugged in and not Ubuntu or the laptop then. Thought I'll mention this here in-case someone asks the same question in future.